# PyCharm excluding directory (src.lambda) from suggestions. Is this a collision with Python lambda name?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

PyCharm is all of the sudden not allowing me to import from just one specific directory.
The directory in question (lambda) is the only one not appearing in "suggestions" as you can see below

If I try to import from src.lambda... the importation fails

[image]

Does somebody know what is going on here?

Comment: Did you try invalidating the caches and restart?

Comment: So you refer to this ? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html

Why that would solve the issue ?

Comment: It could solve the issues if the caches were corrupted. Similar things happened to me and invalidating caches usually solved them.

Comment: it did not solve the issue. What it solved the issue was to rename the directory

Comment: Great. Did you try running your code despite the import error shown in Pycharm? If it did work, then this might be some bug in Pycharm and you could report it to them. If it doesn't run, then maybe Python is having problems with the `lambda` directory name.

Comment: Yes, and it did not work. Looks like it was some kind of collision with the lambda directory name